# Can HTTP method GET be used with "multipart/form-data" encoding?

Tags: http, get

I already used **HTTP** method **POST** `method="post"` with encodings:

- **URL encoded** ✘: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
- **URL encoded** ✔: `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

I also used **HTTP** method **GET** `method="get"` with encoding:

- **URL encoded** ✔: `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Is it possible to also use method **GET** with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. As [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) requests don't have a body, specifying it's [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) doesn't make any sense. Especially `multipart/form-data`, which states the request will have multiple bodies.

This parameter is only used for request types with bodies, like [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) or [PUT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT).

Answer (score 1):

> The enctype attribute can be used only if method="post".

The enctype attribute specifies how the form-data should be encoded when submitting it to the server.

Comment: I already saw people writting `method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It also worked for me. Is enctype simply ignored in this case?

Comment: Yes, I think so, since there's no data to pass.